# Storing just Month and Year in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to save the month/year in SQL Server 2008 with a regular datetime?  I don't need a time stamp and the column is going to store unique mo/yr combinations (i.e. 10-11, 11-11, 12-11, etc,.).

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Without knowing the intended use, it is not possible to advise correctly.  However, storing month and year is easily done in at least three ways:

- use a date field, but always store into it the first day of the month at midnight; then always custom format the date field for display
- add integer year and month fields, and populate them by splitting a date
- add an integer field where you encode it as year * 100 + month or some other useful scheme

Comment: Note that wallyk mentions the [Date data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) in his first option. This is different from a Datetime field. All three of these options make a lot of sense.

Comment: In case you are wondering how to decompose the integer back to year/month, that is how I did using csharp: year = birthday / 100; day = birthday % 100;

Answer (score 3):

Sql Server will store the datetime data in its entirety (year-month-day hour:min:sec.milliSec) no matter what.

When you store your dates, you can make the day the 1st of the month. Just format the dates how you want when you do your queries.

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 2):

From SQLServer 2008 and onwards:

Save as a `Date` column and add the following check constraint to make sure the value is always the first of the month:

```sql
datepart(month, MyDate)<>datepart(month,dateadd(day, -1, MyDate))
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I think a simpler check constraint is `DAY(MyDate) = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You cant only store year and month in a DateTime column. Well, what you can do is default the rest of the values. ie: 2011.10.1.1 , 2011.11.1.1 like that.

Or you can store it as string.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105), 7) AS [MM-YYYY]
```

You should try this